# ORA-31603 when generating ddl for constraints

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am trying to generate ddl for constraints. A snippet from the query:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('CONSTRAINT', constraint_name, owner)
FROM   all_constraints
WHERE  owner      = UPPER('THEOWNER')
  AND    constraint_type IN ('U', 'P', 'R');
```

but getting this:

```
ORA-31603: object "EMPLOYEE_DEPNUM_FK" of type CONSTRAINT not found in schema "THEOWNER"
at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6069
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 8666
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Running the script as a system user. Also tried the script as the `THEOWNER`:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('CONSTRAINT', 'EMPLOYEE_DEPNUM_FK') from dual;
```

The same error. I am able to generate ddl for tables, indexes, views etc but for some constraints.

The following query shows the `THEOWNER` as the owner of the constraint:

```
SELECT owner FROM all_constraints WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='EMPLOYEE_DEPNUM_FK';
```

I can't seem to find the source code for `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` anywhere. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl (CASE WHEN constraint_type = 'R' THEN 'REF_CONSTRAINT' ELSE 'CONSTRAINT' END, constraint_name, owner)
FROM   all_constraints
...
```

as ref-constraints have another type description.